# Word Macro to Mass Hyperlink variable length strings

Tags: vba, hyperlink, macros, ms-word

I've been looking through the forums for a while now trying to find an answer to my problem, and either I'm dense or it hasn't been answered, so here I am.

Long story short, my job involves writing up word documents that list building deficits and provides hyperlinks to images of said deficits. The visible hyperlink text always follows the same format: '[site abbreviation][(image number)].JPG'. For example, if we are looking at 'Administrative Building', our images will be named 'AB(1).JPG', 'AB(2).JPG', etc, often into the mid-hundreds or thousands. In the word document, they are referenced as 'AB1', 'AB2' etc.

Currently, I have a macro that allows me to automatically create a hyperlink once I've selected the text, but I am trying to create a macro that will look through a document (or better yet, a highlighted selection) and assign hyperlinks to any text that starts with the site's abbreviation all at once.

My current attempt at a mass-hyperlinking macro is frustratingly close, but has one major error: while it will correctly hyperlink the first image name it finds, all subsequent images are linked with the next two characters included in the link. For example, if a sentence were to say "This is not correct (AB33), but this is correct (AB34)', my macro will hyperlink the text 'AB34' (which is correct) and 'AB33) ' (which is incorrect).

This is the macro I've been working with thus far (note that the text between the lines of 'XXXX...' are basic instructions for my coworkers to change the link destination as needed)

```
Option Explicit


    Sub Mass_Hyperlink_v_1_1()
'incomplete: selects incorrect text after first link

Dim fileName As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim tag As String
Dim FileType As String
Dim folder As String
Dim space As String
Dim start As String
Dim report_type As String
Dim temp As String

'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
'Do not touch anything above this line

    'Answer the following for the current document. Leave all quotations.

    report_type = "CL"          'CL = Checklist
                                'SR = Site Report

    folder = "Doors"          'The name of the folder you are linking images from
                                'Must match folder exactly

    tag = "FS"                  'Put file prefix here (ex. if link says "AB123", put "AB")

    space = "No"               'Does the image file have a space in it? (ex. if file name is "AB (23)", put "yes")

    FileType = ".JPG"           'make sure filetype extensions match

'Do not touch anything below this line
'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

If space = "Yes" Then
    start = "%20("
    Else: start = "("
End If

If report_type = "CL" Then
    folder = "..\Images\" & folder
    Else: folder = folder
End If

If report_type = "SR" Then
    folder = "Images\" & folder
    Else: folder = folder
End If

Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range

With rng.find
.MatchWildcards = True
    Do While .Execute(findText:=tag, Forward:=False) = True
        rng.MoveStartUntil (tag)
        rng.Select
        Selection.Extend
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend


        'I believe the issue is created here

        Selection.start = Selection.start + Len(tag)

        ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.start - Len(tag), Selection.start).Delete

    fileName = Selection.Text

    filePath = folder & "\" & tag & start & fileName & ")" & FileType

    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, address:= _
        filePath, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:= _
        tag & Selection.Text

    rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart


    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

If I've explained this terribly wrong or not provided enough information, please let me know and I'll try to be more clear. And if there is a helpful resource that I'm simply too dense to have found, please let me know! thank you!

edit: if anyone knows how to only select words that start with the tag as opposed to words with the tag text in them, I'd be incredibly appreciative as well!

Comment: to match just the tag set .MatchWholeWord = True in your find - use the Macro recorder for things like that.  Also if the text is always "not correct" then back out that many characters and see if you match Not Correct.

Comment: Will .MatchWholeWord = True work if the text string includes more than only the tag? for example, would that function allow me to find the tag "AB324" by searching only for "AB"?

And I apologize for not clarifying: the '(not correct)' and '(correct)' in that example were me pointing out where the macro properly linked text versus improperly. that text will not be part of the document.

Comment: No it wouldn't but you can remove that and tell it to matchcase which would.   And it wouldn't pick up Ab but would pick up your examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match a fixed tag followed by a variable number of digits:

```
Sub Tester()
    TagMatches ActiveDocument, "AB"
End Sub


Sub TagMatches(doc As Document, tag As String)
    Dim rng

    Set rng = doc.Range

    With rng.Find
        .Text = tag & "[0-9]{1,}"
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute
            Debug.Print rng.Text
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

See:  http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that solution as soon as I have a free moment!

Comment: thank you so much! I folded that into my macro and it works like a dream! You have no idea how much time your suggestion will be saving me in the future!